# How to show Read More text after 3 lines of text without using library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm creating an app where I need to display text which should only show 3 lines. If the text has exceeded, show `Read More` or `Hide`. I'm using the following code.

```
class CustomLabel extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <View>        
        <Text>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
          eiusmod tempor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
          elit, sed do eiusm Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
          elit, sed do eiusmod tempor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
          adipiscing elit, sed do eiusm Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
          adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
          consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusm Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
          consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor. Lorem ipsum dolor
          sit amet, consectetur
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to accomplish this, but the general idea is to figure out what your height needs to be to accommodate your 3 lines (or whatever your threshold is going to be). Once you have that, you can hide the overflow and implement your show more/less logic.

```css
p {
    height: 55px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusm Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit
  amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusm Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusm Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
  elit, sed do eiusmod tempor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusm Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit
  amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusm Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusm Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
  elit, sed do eiusmod tempor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusm Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit
  amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusm Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusm Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
  elit, sed do eiusmod tempor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusm Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit
  amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusm Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusm Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
  elit, sed do eiusmod tempor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use use **numberOfLines={3}**

```
class CustomLabel extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <View>        
        <Text numberOfLines={3}>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
          eiusmod tempor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
          elit, sed do eiusm Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
          elit, sed do eiusmod tempor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
          adipiscing elit, sed do eiusm Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
          adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
          consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusm Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
          consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor. Lorem ipsum dolor
          sit amet, consectetur
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

output:

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do 
eiusmod tempor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing 
elit, sed do eiusm Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur...